# Obtaining details from configuration profile iOS

Tags: ios

I'm developing a corporate app and wish to access a key value stored in a configuration profile on the device.

Is this possible from within a third party app? I need to get a URL out of a webclip that is installed with a configuration profile so I can force that URL to open in safari from within the application.

I'm not sure where to start with this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The applications are sandboxed.

Comment: Yes, but surely theres a way to read the details of a 3rd party configuration profile? Or is this just completely impossible? I'm sure other applications do it.

Comment: This question was asked on May 2012. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344814/ios-get-configuration-profiles-that-are-installed