# Copy a p12 certificate from OSX which will used by an app when calling web API

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, p12

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10344814/7924605) on stackoverflow so I knew I can't read an installed certification in configuration profile from an app.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Copy the certificate (.p12) which is self-signed from my macbook through AirDrop.
2. Then iPhone will asked me to install it, so I installed.
3. Now I can see the certificate in `Settings->General->Profiles & Device Management`, but in the profile there are red words `Not Verified` below `Signed by`. I guess it is because the certificate is self-signed.
4. I develop an app that use `[NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL: ...]` to request an web page, without `[URLSession: didReceiveChallenge: ...]`.
5. The app got error `Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid."`, which is the same error I got before I installed the certificate.

**UPDATE:** I tried it again and I noticed that the certificate I got is **not signed**, maybe this is the real reason why I failed and the profile shows not verified? Maybe I should ask my colleague who give me this certificate.

What I need is to copy a **self-signed certificate (.p12)** from my OSX into my iPhone/iPad and then develop an app to read it as a credential when calling a web API.

Since each authorized user will get different certificates,  I can't just put the certificate in the app's main bundle.

I know I can download a certificate through an app (maybe with some authorized token), but since the server hasn't developed this api yet, I need to copy certificate manually when I test my app.

Can someone teach me how to copy the certificate and read it from my develop app.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: If this is just a temporary solution for debug reasons until the API is done, how I understand, why not just add the certificate file to the Xcode project/bundle? If you need it to be on the actual device, you cn simply send it by email, open it on the device, add and trust it within the iOS settings app.

Comment: Hi @shallowThought , thank you for your reply. I did send it by email and added into configuration profile, but as I mentioned, I can't read certificate in configuration profile from app, do you have other suggestions about this?.

I also tried use `[NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL: ...]` to request an web page with the certificate in configuration profile, without implement `[URLSession: didReceiveChallenge: ...]`, it still return error (Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid.")

Comment: Did you trust it on the device?

Comment: Yes, I installed it, I can see it in my `Settings->General->Profiles & Device Management`. I used air drop to copy the certificate from my macbook.

Comment: After installing it, you also have to trust it explicitly. It than says "trusted" and (I think) has a green checkmark. MAybe update your question with the new information (What is added/trusted, how, what exact code gives you which exact error).

Comment: Hi @shallowThought, thanks a lot. I've update my question to tell what have I tried with the installed certificate. I guess it was because the certificate is **self-signed**, I can't get a green check-mark on it.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this:

- Create a self signed certificate. Enter a pass-phrase and leave everything else empty:

  `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`
- Send it to yourself via e-mail
- Open the e-mail on the iOS device and open the attached `cert.pem` file
- In the opened settings menu, click `install`:
- Type in your devices pass code
- Confirm by clicking `install`.

-> Result: trusted certificate:

[image]

Comment: hmm... I tried it again and I noticed that the certificate I got is **not signed**, maybe this is the real reason why I failed and the profile shows **not verified**? Maybe I should ask my colleague who give me this certificate.

Comment: That makes sense to me.