# Listing system keychain certificates

Tags: ios, keychain

I'm developing an iOS application which needs access to the system certificates and keys for digitally signing data.

I've done some research and I've found that theoretically it's not possible from a third party app to get access to the system keychain since it only has access to its own keychain.  Here is a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648487/how-to-list-certificates-from-the-iphone-keychain-inside-my-app) explaining that.

However, some applications like the [Cisco AnyConnect](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cisco-anyconnect/id392790924?mt=8) show a list with all the system certificates for VPN configuration. That might mean that THERE ACTUALLY IS a way to get that system certificates list.

This [image](http://s7.postimage.org/h8bhxhmob/IMG_0089_1.png) shows how the certificates are displayed in the cisco app.

I'd be really grateful if somebody could shed some light on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's just a matter of signing your binary using a proper `entitlements.xml` file. [Keychain-dumper](https://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper) does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Looks like you need to have your device Jailbroken for that code to work properly. Extract from [Keychain-dumper](https://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper): _As an aside, the following directions assume the target device has already been jailbroken._

Comment: Any ideas on how to do that without the need of jailbreaking the device?