# Private API on ios to list configuration profiles

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

Is there any private api on iOS that could list all configuration profiles from an iOS App

Note:

1. This app is not required for `AppStore` but in general.
2. MDM is not an option.
3. jailbreak is not an option

Comment: Please check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648487/how-to-list-certificates-from-the-iphone-keychain-inside-my-app

Comment: Hi Piyush, the configuration profiles are not listed in the keychain. So accessing the keychain does not make much sense. Junos Pulse does it via a special vpn plugin which uses a private API to list all configuration profiles. I am interested in calling that private API within an underprivileged app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS get Configuration Profiles that are installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344814/ios-get-configuration-profiles-that-are-installed)

Comment: Answer not available on that thread. That is more restricted on getting vpn configurations.